# elasticsearch children aggregation, missing children aggregator

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to aggregate count of children from matched parents in parent-child mappings as explained [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) and [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-children-aggregation.html)

ES versions: 1.3.2

mappings as follow:

```
{
    "holder": {},
    "unit": {
        "_parent": { "type": "holder" }
    }
}
```

but any query with children aggregation simply return

**Parse Failure [Could not find aggregator type [children] in [count_units]]]**

query that I run as follow:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "count_units": {
            "children": { "type": "unit" }
        }
    }
}
```

what did I miss from the documentations?

Comment: Probably the fact that "Children aggregation" is specified as "Coming in 1.4.0."

Comment: @AndreiStefan Yes my stupid mistake, it was there and I did not see it.